# getDay () unexpected output on the last day of the month

Tags: javascript

I have a script that gives me the days of the week, when I enter the day from 1 to 30 there are no problems, but when I enter the 31st, the script returns the first day of the same month.

```
function myFunction() {
 let numDayOfMonth = 31;
 const arrayDayWeek = ['Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa'];
 let initialDate = new Date();
 initialDate.setDate(numDayOfMonth);
 initialDate.setMonth(4);
 const numDayOfWeek = initialDate.getDay();
 console.log(initialDate);
 const nameDayOfWeek = arrayDayWeek[numDayOfWeek];
 return nameDayOfWeek;
}
```

Current output

> Sat May 01 2021 20:40:48 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)

Expected output

> Mo May 31 2021 20:40:48 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

new Date() would use today's date initially, so that would be 15th June 2021.  When you then try to set the Day to the 31st it wraps back to 01 because June only has 30 days.

To get your expected output you should set the Month first.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working as expected. I will explain.

```
function myFunction() {
  let numDayOfMonth = 31;
  const arrayDayWeek = ['Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa'];
  let initialDate = new Date();              // initialDate will be 15/06/2021
  initialDate.setDate(numDayOfMonth);        // initialDate will be 01/07/2021, because 31/06/2021 doesn't exist
  initialDate.setMonth(4);                   // initialDate will be 01/05/2021
  const numDayOfWeek = initialDate.getDay();
  console.log(initialDate);
  const nameDayOfWeek = arrayDayWeek[numDayOfWeek];
  return nameDayOfWeek;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are setting the day first, then the month, which means you are setting it to the 31st day of the *current* month. If the current month has 30 days, it will roll over to 1.

Instead, use the constructor to specify the values:

```js
function myFunction() {
 let numDayOfMonth = 31;
 const arrayDayWeek = ['Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa'];
 const today = new Date();

 const initialDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 4, numDayOfMonth);

 const numDayOfWeek = initialDate.getDay();
 console.log(initialDate.toLocaleString());
 const nameDayOfWeek = arrayDayWeek[numDayOfWeek];
 return nameDayOfWeek;
}

myFunction();
```